# downloading csv files from a specific site using python

Tags: python, csv

Goal: want to automatize the download of various .csv files from https://wyniki.tge.pl/en/wyniki/archiwum/2/?date_to=2018-03-21&date_from=2018-02-19&data_scope=contract&market=rtee&data_period=3 using Python (this is not the main issue though)

Specifics: in particular, I am trying to download the csv file for the "Settlement price" and "BASE Year"

Problem: when I see the source code for this web page.I see the references to the "Upload" button, but I don't see refences for the csv file(Tbf I am not very good at looking at the source code). As I am using Python (urllib) I need to know the URL of the csv file but don't know how to get it.

This is not a question of Python per se, but about how to find the URL of some .csv that can be downloaded from a web page. Hence, no code is provided.

Comment: You could use a tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) to see the POST request data that is being sent that is triggering the download to occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you inspect the source code from that webpage in particular, you will see that the form to obtain the `csv` file has 3 main inputs:

```
file_type
fields
contracts
```

So, to obtain the csv file for the "Settlement price" and "BASE Year", you would simply do a `POST` request to that same `URL`, passing these as the payload:

```
file_type=2&fields=4&contracts=4
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend wget command with python. WGET is a command to download any file. Once you download the file with wget then you can manipulate the csv file using other library.

I found this wget library for python.
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wget

Regards.
Eduardo Estevez.

Comment: How does WGET help me in this instance? I would still have to give it the URL that I don't know.

Comment: I tried to download the data from wyniki.tge.pl using wget and curl. It's does not work. In my opinion the Button "update" perform a POST request through AJAX to generate the .CSV file. You should contact with the Developer and probably request API access.